# Reducing the time the program takes to calculate large inputs

Tags: python, math, time-complexity

The below code calculates the sum of the result (x*k -y) n amount of times, with the value k starting at 1, and is incremented by 1 each time the loop runs:

```
def invoke(n,x,y):
    k=1
    sum1=0
    while(n > 0):
        result=x*k-y 
        k+=1
        sum1+= result
        n-=1 
    return sum1
```

For instance, calling the function with the values, invoke(2,3,5) would output -1 because for k=1, it is 3*1-5 = -2, and for k=2, it becomes 3*2-5=1. Hence, the program returns -1 as both -2 and 1 are added.

The problem, I am having is that it takes a while to calculate large numbers, is there any way to optimize this?

In an attempt to make it run faster, I wrote a recursive implementation of this program:

```
def invoke1(n,x,y):
     k=0
     if n == 0:
         return 0
     else:
         return x*(k+n)-y + invoke1(n-1,x,y)
```

However, this implementation is not much better as I get an error when calculating large numbers.

Comment: Why do you think the recursive variant would be faster?

Comment: I timed both and both are nearly identical with the recursive a little slower.. recursion limit is 1000.. just scrap the recursive function. it is unnecessary

Comment: In terms of performance, recursion is actually [slower than a simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386375/efficiency-recursion-vs-loop)

Comment: If you just wrote `def invoke(n,x,y): return sum(x*k-y for k in range(1, n+1))` (i.e., normal Python), your question would be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Honestly, I was just testing out different ways of calculating large inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of looking for a way to do the same work faster, you should ask whether you have to do all the work in the first place.

Basically you want to compute:

```
 n
---
\
/     x * k - y
---
k=1
```

With `x` and `y` fixed. If we perform mathematical analysis on it, we know that this is equivalent to:

```
n * (n+1) * x
-------------  - n * y
      2
```

So we can calculate it as:

```
def invoke(n, x, y):
    return n * (n+1) * x / 2 - n * y
```

Or **if** we only perform calculations in the integer domain:

```
def invoke_ints(n, x, y):
    return n * (n+1) * x // 2 - n * y
```

Given the calculations are done in constant time (if the numbers are very huge, actually calculates are typically done in *O(log n)*), the time complexity is constant, if not, these are in *O(log n)*.

The iterative and recursive function both work in *O(n)* (if the computations are in constant time), or *O(n log n)* in case the numbers are that huge that we do the calculations with arbitrary bit length. Recursion will usually slow down the process, since function calls in Python are quite expensive, and Python does not implement *tail call optimization (TCO)*.