# Other alternatives that can be used for goto swift

Tags: ios, swift, goto

Here is my code:

```
func deneme() {

    var buttons: [UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
    let button = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)

    if button.titleLabel?.text == cevapLabel.text {

    }
    else {
        button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

I want to use these codes in if statement. if swift had goto, i could write a code like:

```
    var buttons: [UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]
    A:
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
    let button = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)

    if button.titleLabel?.text == cevapLabel.text {
       goto A
    }
    else {
      button.isHidden = true
    }
```

**purpose of code: hiding buttons. If the text of the buttons in the array is the equal to cevapLabel.text, the random code should restart.**

Comment: A `while` loop?

Comment: @Ahmed F please roll back your edit. It conflicts with authors intent. Author wanted to show what they would like to do but Swift doesn't support it. without seeing the intent it's harder to work out what the author wants to acheive

Comment: @Scriptable yes, my bad. I did it.

Comment: @Moritz Absolutely right, my bad. Thanks for the note :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `repeat-while`:

```
var buttons: [UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]
var currentButton: UIButton?
repeat {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
    currentButton = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)
} while currentButton?.titleLabel?.text == cevapLabel.text

currentButton?.isHidden = true
```

Comment: Although this answer seems to be a typical one, do you have any idea what would be different when comparing with [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49254070/5501940)? let's say as performance wise...

Comment: @AhmadF yours is recursive, while this is an iterative approach, so I think this should perform better

Comment: @AhmadF in general recursion has lower performance than loops, since a recursion requires calling the method `n`-times, which means n times creating a entry on call stack... see this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386375/efficiency-recursion-vs-loop or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: its worked ! thank you. but there is an another problem.what can i do for a hidden button to avoid it getting hidden again?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `repeat-while` [Milan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253818/5501940), you also could achieve it by implementing a *function recursion*, let's assume that your function should be named as `showOrHide()`:

```
var buttons: [UIButton] = [buttonA,buttonB,buttonC,buttonD,buttonE]

showOrHide()

func showOrHide() {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttons.count)))
    let button = buttons.remove(at: randomNumber)

    if button.titleLabel?.text == cevapLabel.text {
       showOrHide()
    }
    else {
      button.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional version. The first line gets the indexes of all the buttons that do not have `cevapLabel.text` as their label. You then pick an index from the resulting array and delete the item with that index.

```
let eligibleIndexes = buttons.enumerated()
                          .filter{ $0.1.titleLabel?.text ?? "" != cevapLabel.text }
                          .map{ $0.0 }
let indexToGo = eligibleIndexes[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(eligibleIndexes.count)))]
let CurrentButton = buttons.remove(at: indexToGo)
currentButton.isHidden = true
```

It might need some tweaking because it is completely untested.